# How to add extra stop words in addition to default stopwords in wordcloud?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-analysis, stop-words, word-cloud

I would like to add certain words to the default stopwords list used in wordcloud. Current code:

```
all_text = " ".join(rev for rev in twitter_clean.text)
stop_words = ["https", "co", "RT"]
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stop_words, background_color="white").generate(all_text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

When I use the custom stop_words variable, words such as "is", "was" , and "the" are all interpreted and displayed as high frequency words. However,  when I use the default stopwords list (no stopwords argument) then there are many other words that are displayed as highly frequent. How do I add my custom stop_words variable along with the default stopwords list to my wordcloud?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just append your list to the built-in STOPWORDS list:

From the wordcloud documentation:

> stopwords : set of strings or None. The words that will be eliminated.
>   If None, the build-in STOPWORDS list will be used.

So you can simply append STOPWORDS to your custom list and use it

```
all_text = " ".join(rev for rev in twitter_clean.text)
stop_words = ["https", "co", "RT"] + list(STOPWORDS)
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stop_words, background_color="white").generate(all_text)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Cast it to a list or the custom list to a set. Edited the code.

Answer (score 3):

**By adding your custom stopwords list to the wordcloud.STOPWORDS set**

The built in STOPWORDS from wordcloud is a python set.

```
from wordcloud import STOPWORDS

print(type(STOPWORDS))
```

Output

```
<class 'set'>
```

We can add to this set using `set.update()` as shown:

```
stop_words = STOPWORDS.update(["https", "co", "RT"])
```

Now update the stopwords in wordcloud

```
wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords = stop_words, background_color="white").generate(all_text)
```

Comment: Not a great solution as this will change the `STOPWORDS` value itself. Will work on most occasions but if used without care might lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Just get the list of original stop words with `from wordcloud import STOPWORDS` then append your list. Like this `[STOPWORDS.add(n) for n in custon_stop_words]`

Answer (score 0):

```
stopwords.update(["https", "co"])
```

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful as they don't explain *why* the code solves the problem. Please add an explanation to your answer.